Parallelization in Python
I need to solve N independent constrained LSQ problems and want to do it using parallel processing (e.g. N ~ 50k). Usually I use Matlab parfor which is very straightforward. I want to do same using Python.
I am using the following code, but with no success (note: my problem is rather complex, but the code below summarizes it, and is easy to understand):
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

data = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]])

U = np.zeros((4, 3))
def dummyFUNCTION(i):
        X = data
        X[:, i] *= 3
        return X[:, i]

# This is what I have and what I want
for i in range (0,3):
    ui = dummyFUNCTION(i)
    U[:, i] = ui

print(U)

# This is my attempt to parallelize and is not working
# I am under IDLE Shel 3.12.1

U = np.zeros((4, 3))
with  multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        ui = [pool.apply_async(dummyFUNCTION, [i]) for i in range(0,3)]
        for idx, val in enumerate(ui):
                U[:, idx] = val.get()
       pool.close()    

print(U)


What do you mean by "is not working"? Results are wrong or the performance is does not fit your requirements?

Btw, pool.close is AFAIK not needed in a with section.

Hi Jerôme, Not working means I get no results. I expected the same outcome as I get in the first trivial approach, although faster. I deleted pool.close, but the problem still remains. Thanks and Regards, Abdul

I think the problem is that you modify data in the function which is a process-local array that should not be modified. You must provide the input in parameter of your dummyFUNCTION function and return the output. You cannot mutate data of the master process because you cannot mutate data of another process unless it is manually/explicitly shared.

If you had moved everything in a main function except functions, then you would have seen an error reporting data cannot be accessed from the function. Globals should be avoided in parallel computing because they cause a lot of issues (hidden dependencies a.k.a. "spooky action at distance", increased chance of race conditions or over-locking resulting in deadlocks). They should also be avoided in software engineering because of (other) issues too. Globals are bad so please avoid them like the plague (except constants defined at init time).

Hi Jérôme, I have modified a little. Still not working. Thanks for your feedbacks

I suspect with X = data you intended to copy data. It does not, python names do not work that way. Probably you want to construct a new object, I guess X = np.array(data) or whatever np.array syntax for copy is or https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html .

You still access and mutate a global variable. No global access should be done, that is, you should not access data directly. By the way, I get the correct result now with some modifications (reported by CPython as error and following the above advices). Please read the comments more carefully ;) .

Yesterday I saw a solution provided by rpanai, and wanted to test it today. Unfortunately, I cannot find it now. Was it deleted? Thanks to all.

Yes, it was deleted. Maybe you should have upvoted it if it was useful.

Although I found a way to perform parallelization, indeed it only works within the script, for example:
if name == "main":
with Pool(4) as p:
result = p.map(dummyFUNCTION, args)
vector = np.array(result)
np.append(U, vector.T, axis=1)
My problem still persists since I need to use parallelization within a class, that I constructed for estimation purposes. This class is called in my script.  So, what I need is to use parallelization independently. Can anyone please help me on this issue?
